# Is it correct that the "jackson library" is not included in a spring boot project without spring web added to project dependency?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I recently started studying spring.

I heard from others that spring already provides jackson library dependencies, but I was wondering if this means that "**spring web**" supports jackson or **spring boot (or spring)** supports jackson.

I am currently working on a spring boot project without adding a "spring web" dependency, and I was wondering if I should add a jackson dependency to `build.gradle`(gradle) or `pom.xml`(maven) manually.

In my project, which doesn't have the spring web dependencies I mentioned, the project can't find jackson-related features (like objectMapper) when I import them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both support Jackson as Spring Boot builds on top of Spring. The fact that something supports something doesn't mean it is automatically included.

Adding `spring-web` won't add the jackson dependencies. Only if you would add `spring-boot-starter-web` it would add those as they come transitively. To include only jackson dependencies you can ofcourse add the individual dependencies but it might be better to add `spring-boot-starter-json` instead.

Comment: This, and I would add that if you want a little more insight into what `spring-boot-starter-json` does for you vs what you would need to do were it not included, just put a breakpoint inside `JacksonAutoConfiguration`

Comment: The `JacksonAutoConfiguration` has nothing to do with `spring-boot-starter-json` that is part of the regular Spring Boot autoconfiguration. So even when adding the libraries manually it will invoke the `JacksonAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: Hmm... now I'm a bit confused, what does `spring-boot-starter-json` do for you, besides adding Jackson dependencies?

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-json` does exactly that add the Jackson dependencies, which means the jackson library. The `JacksonAutoConfiguration` is part of Spring Boot and is already there as it is part of the regular `spring-boot-autoconfiguration` dependency which contains all possible auto configurations (expect those for the actuator which are part of the `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfiguration` dependency).